# command to cut and copy the sub directories and files to specified directory in windows

Tags: windows, command

My question is

I have 3 directories and 5 files in C:\test

I want cut and paste all the files and directories under C:\test to C:\demo through command line in windows. Plz help me in this

Thx in advance

Comment: How is this programming related? I'm not even sure it's worthy of moving to ServerFault...!

Answer (score 1):

```
robocopy /s C:\test C:\demo /MOVE
```

robocopy with /MOVE moves all files and if you use /s , also subdirectories.

but without /MOVE it just copy files from source to destination.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the directory names:

```
move c:\test\directory1 c:\demo
move c:\test\directory2 c:\demo
move c:\test\directory3 c:\demo
move c:\test\directory4 c:\demo
move c:\test\directory5 c:\demo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy)

xcopy c:\test c:\demo /e /h

Answer (score 0):

XCopy is old-school, Robocopy's where it's at

```
robocopy C:\test C:\demo /MIR
```